# pulsing opacity with javascript

Tags: javascript, function

I've written a function in javascript to make the opacity of an element go from some low number up to 1 and then down again.  I know that this could be done with Jquery but I wanted to write it myself.  My question is:  is there a shorter/more elegant way to write this?  It works perfectly but seems clunky.

```
function opacityPulse(id,dimLevel){
    var opacity=dimLevel;
    var hump=0;
    var myVar=setInterval(function(){myFunction()},30);
    function myFunction(){
        if((opacity<1) && (!hump)){
            document.getElementById(id).style.cssText="opacity:"+opacity+";";
            opacity=opacity+.01;
        }
        else if((opacity>.99) && (!hump)){
            hump=1;
        }
        else if((opacity>dimLevel) && (hump)){
            document.getElementById(id).style.cssText="opacity:"+opacity+";";
            opacity=opacity-.01;
        }
        else{
            clearInterval(myVar);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, you could start by indenting it? It is difficult to read this way.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the opacity?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions of the form "This code works, but I think it could be better" are usually better asked on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps better suited for CodeReview...

Comment: The more elegant way and PROPER way is to use a css transition. You are already assigning opacity as style attribute so why to bother using javascript for this stuff? And +1 for the CodeReview

Answer (score 1):

Set `window.toggle = 0.01;` and `window.opacity = 0.98;`
Here we are incrementing the opacity value by amount of `toggle` on each interval. Toggle also serves as a switch to increment or decrement opacity.

```
function opacityPulse(id){
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if(toggle==0.01){
      setIncrementedOpacity(element);
      if(opacity > 0.98){
        toggle = -0.01;
      }
    }else{
      setIncrementedOpacity(element);
      if(opacity < 0.02){
          toggle = 0.01;
      }
    }
}
```

Set Opacity;

```
function setIncrementedOpacity(element){
    opacity = opacity + toggle;
    element.style.opacity = opacity + "";
    element.style.filter  = 'alpha(opacity='+opacity+')'; //IE fallback
}
```

Repeat using interval;

```
setInterval(function(){
      opacityPulse("youarehere");
}, 8);
```

Also, I wouldn't recommend using this because the same can be achieved using css.